# How to put string text file into array in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I manage to read string file from txt file and i managed to print it.How can i put them into array?I know how to put integers into array but putting string make me confused.If someone can help me, i will be very glad.
For example input file is:

```
Corona
CS512
stay
home
safe
```

I can print these but i have difficulty to put them into array.

```
.text
    .globl main

main:


    li $v0,13               # open_file syscall code = 13
        la $a0,fileName         # get the file name
        li $a1,0            # file flag = read (0)
        syscall
        move $s0,$v0            # save the file descriptor. $s0 = file

    #read the file
    li $v0, 14      # read_file syscall code = 14
    move $a0,$s0        # file descriptor
    la $a1,fileWords    # The buffer that holds the string of the WHOLE file
    la $a2,1024     # hardcoded buffer length
    syscall

    # print whats in the file
    la $a0,fileWords
    li $v0, 4       # read_string syscall code = 4
    lb $v1,1($a0)  
    la $a0,$v1   
    syscall


    #Close the file
        li $v0, 16              # close_file syscall code
        move $a0,$s0            # file descriptor to close
        syscall


.data

fileName: .asciiz "C:/Users/JonDoe/Desktop/input.txt"
fileWords: .space 1024
```

Comment: _"How can i put them into array"_ What are _them_?